# how can I get a unknown length string from a webpage

Tags: string, perl, url

I need to get a string in perl whose length is varying each day. Look at the URL content below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Index of /isos/preFCS5.3/LATESTGOODCVP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of /isos/preFCS5.3/LATESTGOODCVP</h1>
<table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last      modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="/isos/preFCS5.3/">Parent   Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso">CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso</a></td><td align="right">19-Jul-2011 03:32  </td><td align="right">816M</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="ChangeLog-LATEST.2011-07-19-03h.30m.01s">ChangeLog-LATEST.2011-07-19-03h.30m.01s</a></td><td align="right">19-Jul-2011 03:32  </td><td align="right"> 16K</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="is.iso">is.iso</a></td><td align="right">19-Jul-2011 03:32  </td><td align="right">816M</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="md5SUM">md5SUM</a></td><td align="right">19-Jul-2011 03:32  </td><td align="right">111 </td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at www.google.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

You can see a string named "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso".
I need to get that into $name.
the string CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso will keep on changing everyday
say CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.39.iso or CVP-LATEST-5.3.39a.iso or to CVP-LATEST-6.1.iso or CVP-LATEST-6.23.23.112.iso.

Is there any way I can get this ?

Here is the code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $oldVersion = CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso;
my $url        = 'http://www.google.com/isos/preFCS5.3/LATESTGOODCVP/';

my $newPage = get($url)
or die "Cannot retrieve contents from $url\n";

if ( $newPage =~ /href=\"CVP-LATEST-5\.3\.0\.(\d\d)/ ) {
my $version = $1;

if ( $version != $oldVersion ) {
    my $status = getstore($url . "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.$version.iso",
                          "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.$version.iso");
} else {
    print "Already at most recent version\n";
}

} else {
die "Cannot find version tag in contents from $url\n";
}
```

Here if you see the code its getting only the number(xx) after 5.3.0."XX" and is of known length that is 2.

Is there anyway I can change it so that it will read the whole filename ie. CVP-LATEST-XXXXXX*.iso  and then compare it with the  $oldversion  ?

Please note the string "CVP-LATEST-" and ".iso" remains constant, but later numbers change and can also contain alphabets.
Also note that there is one more file called is.iso in the URL content. I don't want to get that.

Comment: Please accept the answers to some of your previous questions; you're discouraging people from answering your questions by not doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if ( $newPage =~ /href=\"CVP-LATEST-(.*?)\.iso\"/ ) {
    my $name = "CVP-LATEST-${1}.iso";
```

`$name` contains the whole filename.

Comment: So what does $name contain ?  does it have the whole string(CVP-LATEST-XX*.iso)? Because I need the whole string to be in $name.  Also I see only 1 "  in you code? any idea where to end that " ? sorry I cant try the code now since I don't have access to that link as of now

Comment: Thanks, But I think you missed a  "(double_quote) in line 1. Can I know wheres the other "(double_quote)  ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a module that knows how to parse HTML when you want to parse HTML.

Your Question is Asked Frequently:

```
perldoc -q url

How do I extract URLs?

use HTML::SimpleLinkExtor;
...
my $extor = HTML::SimpleLinkExtor->new();
$extor->parse($newPage);
my($version) = grep /^CVP-LATEST-.*\.iso/, $extor->href;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the time stamp of the website using this module ?    Im just confused which parameter I should use to check for the update. Whether check for filename or the timestamp.

Comment: What does "time stamp of the website" mean when you say it?

Comment: if you look at the above web-source you can see a time "19-Jul-2011 03:32" in the same line as "CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso" This time is nothing but the file updated time. I wonder is it good idea to get the time in epoch and compare wth stored time, instead getting the file name(CVP-LATEST-5.3.0.37.iso) and comparing it.

Answer (score 0):

the secret to html regexes , not doublequote

```
/href="([^"]*)"/i
```